# Subtract each column by the preceding column on Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using the following code I can build a simple table with the current COVID-19 cases worldwide, per country:

```
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv"

raw_data = pd.read_csv(url, sep=",")
raw_data.drop(['Province/State','Lat','Long'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
plot_data = raw_data.groupby('Country/Region').sum()
```

The plot_data is a simple DataFrame:

[image]

What I would like to do now is to subtract the values on each column by the values on the column on a prior day - i.e., I wan to get the new cases per day.

If I do something like plot_data['3/30/20'].add(-plot_data['3/29/20']), it works well. But if I do something like plot_data.iloc[:,68:69].add(-plot_data.iloc[:,67:68]), I got two columns with NaN values. I.e. Python tries to "preserve" de columns header and doesn't perform the operation the way I would like it to.

My goal was to perform this operation in an "elegant way". I was thinking something in the lines of plot_data.iloc[:,1:69].add(-plot_data.iloc[:,0:68]). But of course, if it doesn't work as the single-column example, it doesn't work with multiple columns either (as Python will match the column headers and return a bunch of zeros/NaN values).

Maybe there is a way to tell Python to ignore the headers during an operation with a DataFrame? I know that I can transform my DataFrame into a NumPy array and do a bunch of operations. However, since this is a simple/small table, I thought I would try to keep using a DataFrame data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @Serge Ballesta! Your answer is exactly the type of "elegant solution" I was looking for. The only comment is the shift sign should be "positive".

plot_data - plot_data.shift(1, axis=1)

This way we bring the historical figures forward one day and now I can subtract it from the actual numbers on each day.

Answer (score 0):

The good old `shift` can be used on the horizontal axis:

```
plot_data - plot_data.shift(-1, axis=1)
```

should be what you want.